# Java Generics MergeSort, exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException error

Tags: java, generics, mergesort

I wrote a java program for MergeSort using java generics. However I get following errors, I don't understand where I have gone wrong. please Help me out

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at src.MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:9)
    at src.MergeSort.main(MergeSort.java:57)

package src;
    import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class MergeSort {

  // sort array of type T using the Mergesort algorithm
  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] sort(T[] arr) {
  if (arr.length > 1){
      T[] firstHalf =  (T[]) new Object[arr.length/2];
      System.arraycopy(arr, 0, firstHalf, 0, arr.length /2);
      sort(firstHalf);

 int secondHalfLength = arr.length -arr.length/2;
 T[] secondHalf = (T[]) new Object[secondHalfLength];
 System.arraycopy(arr, arr.length/2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
 sort(secondHalf);
 merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, arr);

  }


      return arr;
  }

  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(T[] arr1, T[] arr2, T[] temp) {
  int current1 = 0;
  int current2 = 0;
  int current3 = 0;

  while(current1 < arr1.length && current2 < arr2.length){
      if (arr1[current1].compareTo(arr2[current2]) < 0)
          temp[current3++] = arr1[current1++];
      else
          temp[current3++] = arr2[current2++];

          }

  while (current1 < arr1.length)
  temp[current3++] = arr1[current1++];
  while (current2 < arr2.length)
  temp[current3++] = arr2[current2++];


  }




  public static void main(String[] args) {



// sort list of Characters
Character[] charArr = {'H','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','!'};

charArr = MergeSort.<Character>sort(charArr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArr));

// sort list of Integers
Integer[] intArr = {23,4,15,8,42,16};

intArr = MergeSort.<Integer>sort(intArr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating `Object[]`?

Comment: You have an `object` in your `Array` that is not implementing `comparable`  interface

Comment: because I couldn't create new generics array using T[] firstHalf = new T[arr.length/2];

Comment: so how do I create new generics array for firstHalf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, it's because your type parameter is actually being erased to `Comparable`.

Remember, generics are erased *to their bounding type*. In most cases, where there is no bounding type, type parameters would be erased to `Object`, but here, because you're bounding `T` by `Comparable`, `T` is erased to `Comparable`. Thus, casts like this:

```
T[] firstHalf =  (T[]) new Object[arr.length/2];
```

Become

```
Comparable[] firstHalf = (Comparable[]) new Object[arr.length / 2];
```

And because `Object` doesn't implement `Comparable`, the cast fails at runtime.

The solution? Simply make your arrays `Comparable[]`. Then your cast won't fail at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. I used T[] firstHalf =  (T[]) new Comparable [arr.length/2]; instead of T[] firstHalf =  (T[]) new Object[arr.length/2]; and it worked

Comment: However I get "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Comparable[] to T[]" do you know what does that mean or how can I avoid it. Thanks

Comment: @user3612693 That's unfortunately a byproduct of how generics were implemented in Java. It means that the compiler cannot prove that the cast will not throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime. If you implemented your generics right, you should be able to prove to yourself that the cast is always safe, and so you can stick a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` onto the assignment. If you take a look at Java's Collections framework, you can see that the same method is used there.